# Is there some way to use std::remove_if on std::string_view iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, string-view

I'm wanting to effectively trim an already created `std::string_view` using an iterator that doesn't point to the trimmed characters thanks to `std::remove_if()`. However, I can't use `std::remove_if()` on a `std::basic_string_view::iterator` directly because that's really a `std::basic_string_view::const_iterator` and `std::remove_if()` can't take non-moveable iterators as arguments.

The only workaround I've though of is casting the `std::string_view` to a `std::string` and then taking the iterator. Here's an example of that:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    std::string_view foo{"Whitepace...\nThe  Final    Frontier"};
    
    const auto is_space{
        [](const auto& character) {
            return std::isspace(character, std::locale{});
        }
    };
    
    // Doesn't compile
    //auto without_conversion{
    //    std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), is_space)
    //};
    
    // Works, for the most part.
    auto with_conversion{
        std::remove_if(std::string{foo}.begin(), std::string{foo}.end(), is_space)
    };
```

But this kinda defeats the whole point of using `std::string_view`, as a `string_view` constructed from this iterator wouldn't be viewing the original string.

Is there some (preferably elegant) way to do this while keeping the view on the original string? Perhaps some way to make the `string_view` iterator non-const?

Comment: `std::remove_if(std::string{foo}.begin(), std::string{foo}.end(), is_space)` -- How could this work with the `begin()` and `end()` iterators referring to two different `std::string` instances?

Comment: Use a different algorithm, such as `std::copy_if`.

Comment: Define what "trim" means to you exactly. Because traditionally, trimming a string means ignoring whitespace only from the ends of the string, not in the middle. And that is something easily workable with const iterators, simply reduce the range that the iterators represent, and `std::string` has a constructor that accepts a range of iterators. But the code presented is trying to ignore all whitespace throughout a string, and that is harder to deal with using const iterators.

Comment: A string_view is a view into a constant character buffer, for example into a string literal. You cannot modify a string literal. You need to make a copy. There is no way around it.

Comment: Working with `std::span` instead might help (original data should not be `const`) `char buffer[] = "Your string"; std::span view{buffer}; std::remove_if(view.begin(), view.end(), is_space)` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ea57beKjY).

Answer (score 2):

`std::string_view` is a constant view of the string sequence.

For example, `begin` returns a `const_iterator`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/begin

Maybe you will have better luck with `std::span`, however take into account that literals in the program are always immutable.
You have to make a copy first anyway.

Also your last line doesn't do what you think because you are iterating over different temporaries, even if it compiles.

The correct code is, for example:

```
    std::string FOO = foo;
    auto with_conversion{
        std::remove_if(FOO.begin(), FOO.end(), is_space)
    };
```

In other words, the whole idea of your program (that you can modify a "program" string) is flawed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to trim a `string_view` of spaces, and store the result in a `std::string`, then you should choose the appropriate algorithm that allows `const` iterators.

One such algorithm is [std::copy_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string_view foo{"Whitepace...\nThe  Final    Frontier"};
    std::string result;
    std::copy_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(result), [](char ch) 
                { return !std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); });
    std::cout << result;
}
```

Output:

```
Whitepace...TheFinalFrontier
```